# GAE/P: Dealing with eventual consistency

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In may app, I have the following process:

1. Get a very long list of people
2. Create an entity for each person
3. Send an email to each person (step 2 must be completed before step 3 starts)

Because the list of people is very large, I don't want to put them in the same entity group.

In doing step 3, I can query the list of people like this:

```
Person.all()
```

Because of eventual consistency, I might miss some people in step 3.  What is a good way to ensure that I am not missing anyone in step 3?

Is there a better solution than this?:

```
while Person.all().count() < N:
    pass
for p in Person.all()
    # do whatever
```

EDIT:

Another possible solution came to mind.  I could create a linked list of the people.  I can store a link to the first one, he can link to the second one and so one.  It seems that the performance would be poor however, because you'd be doing each get separately and wouldn't have the efficiencies of a query.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: I reread your post and saw that you don't want to put them all in the same entity group. I'm not sure how to guarantee strong consistency without doing so. You might want to restructure your data so that you don't have to put them in the same entity group, but in several. Perhaps depending on some aspect of a group of Person entities? (e.g., mailing list they are on, type of email being sent, etc.) Does each Person only contain a name and an email address, or are there other properties involved?

[Google suggests a a few other alternatives](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency):

> If your application is likely to encounter heavier write usage, you may need to consider using other means: for example, you might put recent posts in a **memcache with an expiration** and display a mix of recent posts from the memcache and the Datastore, or **you might cache them in a cookie**, **put some state in the URL**, **or something else entirely**. The goal is to find a caching solution that provides the data for the current user for the period of time in which the user is posting to your application. Remember, if you do a get, a put, or any operation within a transaction, you will always see the most recently written data.

So it looks like you may want to investigate those possibilities, although I'm not sure how well they would translate to what your app needs.

**ORIGINAL POST**: Use [ancestor queries.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Ancestor_Paths)

From Google's ["Structuring Data for Strong Consistency"](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency):

> To obtain strongly consistent query results, you need to use an ancestor query limiting the results to a single entity group. This works because entity groups are a unit of consistency as well as transactionality. All data operations are applied to the entire group; an ancestor query won't return its results until the entire entity group is up to date. If your application relies on strongly consistent results for certain queries, you may need to take this into consideration when designing your data model. This page discusses best practices for structuring your data to support strong consistency.

So when you create a Person entity, set a parent for it. I believe you could even just have a specific entity be the "parent" of all the others, and it should give you strong consistency. (Although I like to structure my data a bit with ancestors anyway.)

```
# Gives you the ancestor key
def ancestor_key(kind, id_or_name):
    return db.Key.from_path(kind, id_or_name)

# Kind is the db model your using (should be 'Person' in this case) and
# id_or_name should be the key id or name for the parent
new_person = Person(your_params, parent=ancestor_key('Kind', id_or_name)
```

You could even do queries at that point for all the entities with the same parent, which is nice. But that should help you get more consistent results regardless.